# Scope not being completely separate between two class implementations

Tags: c++, class, global-variables, scope

I have some code that is basically like this:

```
#include "MyClass.h"

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const char *items[4] = {"apple", "orange", "banana", "pear"};
MyClass::MyClass () {
   cout << "items: " << items[0] << items[1] << items[2] << items[3] << endl;
}
```

In another class implementation file I have another global variable named items which is an array of another type (custom class). Neither implementation file includes the other so I thought that the scope would be different and it should be fine to use items as a variable name in both places. Additionally, if I delete the declaration of items in either class then the compiler complains about it not being defined where it is used in that class. That seems to support my belief that the scope should be separate. When I run this however the output is "lnU�knUVWnUjnU every time. If I change the type of items in the other class to also be a const char* array then it acts as I would expect in each class. Unfortunately the code depends on a mess of other code so it's extremely difficult to give a working example. I'm using gcc 4.3.2 if that matters. Can anybody shed some light on what's going on here?

Comment: Thanks, that is helpful and is a simple way to resolve the problem. Is it normal though that a variable in one file be affecting another if the code from one isn't included in the other (either directly or indirectly)? I thought that the implementation files should be in different scopes. Edit: Looks like the comment was deleted but the suggestion was to declare the variables as static.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see a mess of code. You could prepare a simple example. Without it it is difficult to say why a garbage is printed out,

In the code snippet you showed array items has internal linkage. So any other declaration with the same name in othe modules can not influence to this module.

The program can have undefined behaviour if the same name in the same module is declared as having internal and external linkage. However I can say nothing because I do not see a simple program that demonstrates the problem.